# Value Subtraction between two column

Tags: sql

This is two tbale with Data

```
Table1                                    Table2
ID ColA                                   ID ColB
01 10                                     01 20
02 20                                     02 Null
03 30                                     03 30
04 25                                     04 Null
```

so i Want to subtraction from Col1 to Col2

already i write sql Query but it not properly working

```
select (Table1.ColA-Table2.ColB)as Temp from Table1 
inner join Table2 on Table1.ID Table2.ID
```

so my question is when null value geting from table2 that time subtraction not done so what will do to solve this problem

i want to when value is null that time take value as 0

Comment: what's your `RDBMS`? you may use `ISNULL`(MS SQL),`NVL` (Oracle),`IFNULL`(My SQL) or `COALESCE` (Postgre and Others), depends on your `RDBMS`

Comment: @Farhęg, COALESCE is available on every one you mention.

Comment: @GolezTrol yes I have already mentioned it

Answer (score 2):

You can use COALESCE to default `null` to `0`:

```
select COALESCE(Table1.ColA, 0) - COALESCE(Table2.ColB, 0) as Temp 
from Table1 inner join Table2 on Table1.ID Table2.ID
```

COALESCE accepts multiple parameters and returns the first non-null value.

In some databases, there is a shorthand function for COALESCE if you only need two parameters. These functions may have names like `nvl`, `ifnull`, `isnull`, depending on the database, or may not exist at all. `COALESCE` itself on the other hand is available in most databases, so it's a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server or TSQL use `isnull()` like this:

```
select (isnull(Table1.ColA, 0) - isnull(Table2.ColB, 0))as Temp from Table1 
inner join Table2 on Table1.ID Table2.ID
```

If you use another DBMS use `COALESCE` or `ifnull()` instead of `isnull()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try IFNULL function of sql or mysql

```
select ((IFNULL(Table1.ColA, 0))- (IFNULL(Table2.ColB, 0))) as Temp from Table1 inner join Table2 on Table1.ID = Table2.ID
```